# Index of non-number element in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equality, control-theory, transfer-function

I have defined an array with transfer functions inside it. How can I find the position of a certain transfer function inside that array?

```
s = tf('s') % defining a transfer function
array = [s, s^2, s^3];
>> find(array==s)
undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'tf'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare each element of the array with s using `isequal`:

```
arrayfun(@(x)isequal(x,s),array)
```